# How do I leave out/surpress particular default \usepackage headers when exporting to LaTeX?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

When exporting to LaTeX from org-mode, it seems that several `\usepackage` headers are added by default. However, what if I want to disable one of them (not all), because I will manually specify a replacement to that package later? The [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-header-and-sectioning.html#LaTeX-header-and-sectioning) seems to only talk about adding new headers but I'm not sure about surpressing a particular header instead.